# Parameters in Path Segments of URL

Tags: http, url, https, ftp, ftps

There is one interesting thing in URL format:
Parameters in Path Segments of URL.

For more information see section "2.2.5" in
"**O'Reilly - HTTP - The Definitive Guide**".

This book can be found freely in Internet.

or in official specification
https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt
section 3.3.

> 3.3. Path Component
>
> The path component contains data, specific to the authority (or the
>   scheme if there is no authority component), identifying the resource
>   within the scope of that scheme and authority.
>
> ```
>   path          = [ abs_path | opaque_part ]
>
>   path_segments = segment *( "/" segment )
>   segment       = *pchar *( ";" param )
>   param         = *pchar
>
>   pchar         = unreserved | escaped |
>                   ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | ","
> ```

Let's consider the following URL:

```
http://www.example.com/first-segment/second-segment/index.html?type=HelloWorld
```

Here `/first-segment/second-segment/index.html` is a Path part of URL.

1. And `first-segment` is a first segment of that Path
2. `second-segment` is a second segment of that Path
3. `index.html` is a third segment of that Path

It is stated in that book that each segment could have individual Parameters separated by semicolon ";". In our example it could be:

```
http://www.example.com/first-segment;f1=WWW/second-segment;s1=1;s2=2/index.html;i1=100;abc=200?type=HelloWorld
```

1. Here `f1` - parameter for `first-segment`
2. `s1` and `s2` - parameters for `second-segment`
3. `i1` and `abc` parameters for `index.html`

The question is: do you know any practical examples of such Parameters in URLs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know any example of exactly parameters in the path segment.

But close example is connection and SFTP parameters in (expired) [SFTP URL proposal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04).

There's one proposed [connection parameter](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04#section-5.1), the `fingerprint` for SSH host key fingerprint:

```
sftp://username:password;fingerprint=ssh-dss-0b-77-...@example.com/
```

And one proposed [SFTP parameter](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04#section-5.2), the `typecode` for transfer mode (ascii vs. binary). There's no official example, but it should be like:

```
sftp://username:password@example.com/path/file;typecode=i
```

(what actually, while semantically different, has the syntax of your "path" parameter)