# Is there something similar to C# connection string for FTP connection?

Tags: c#, ftp

Is there something similar to C# connection string for FTP connection? Something I can write as a full string and manage easily like:

```
ftp://username:password@domain:port
```

I explain more what I'm trying to do. I'm writing a small console application that should, let's keep this example simple, download all file from a FTP. I would like to use a command line query similar to the one we use for nuget package for example. A good example is this one:

```
Update-database -connectionString "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Local;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient" -verbose
```

So for my FTP it sill be something similar to

```
Download-Ftp -ftp "ftp://usr202:P@ssw0rd@example.com:21"
```

But also with more details like

```
Download-Ftp -ftp "ftp://usr202:P@ssw0rd@example.com:21;Sftp=false;AnyOtherFtpParameter=value"
```

Of course I can do it myself. My question here and now is. Is there already something, some standard, a better way to manage this or no nothing?

Comment: You just need to somehow escape `@` in your `P@ssw0rd`. You may use a [UriBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_UriBuilder__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_Int32_) for this: `new UriBuilder("ftp", "example.com", 21) { UserName = "usr202", Password = Uri.EscapeDataString("P@ssw0rd") }.Uri`

Comment: For SFTP, use `sftp://`, not separate `Sftp` parameter of `ftp://` URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a well-formed FTP URL you can use the standard  [`System.Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.8) class.

Your second example with extra options is not a well-formed URL and I would recommend against implementing something odd like that.

Since you're writing a command-line application, I would instead suggest implementing command line options (i.e. switches) for those extra settings.

Comment: Interesting link. I'm still reading it but I have just one more question about this, for confirmation. An Uri can represent a file or a folder, right? (and many other things I guess)

Comment: Yes. For simplicity just think of it as a URL, just like you see in your address bar right now.

Comment: +1 – Though note that URL can contain additional parameters – While it's rarely, if ever, used. See [Parameters in Path Segments of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40440004/850848).

Comment: @Martin Very interesting, thanks! I guess what I was trying to say was that what the OP has presented isn't part of a standard FTP URL, so he shouldn't try to use something non-standard.